# what happens to likes in facebook if i change page title

Tags: facebook

I've used this code to have a like btn on my site:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=URL_OF_YOUR_WEBSITE&amp;send=false&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=true&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=80&amp" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

now when ppl press like it says they "user like's title-of-site"

My q: what if i change the title of my site (which appears on their profile since they hit like button)? will it delete all the likes i have? will it change on ppl's profiles where its written they have "liked" my page?

thnx! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the likes are linked to the url, not to the title of your page - so no, it won't affect the number of likes on the page if you change the page title, only if you change the url.